# the simcardio is not available in java 1.7?

Tags: java

I am trying to work the Java smartcardio API but I can not find its classes in Java 1.7.  At this page stands it is in JSR 268 which was released on 11 Dec, 2006
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/
Do someone know the reason why I can not import the ATR classes? Do I have to import the api? if yes where can I find the jar?

[image]

Comment: Did you change java execution environment? https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-with-java7.htm

Comment: @Beri Screenshot shows that is true

Answer (score 0):

The Smart Card I/O API is available in JDK 7, I am able to import its classes successfully.

[image]

The problem lies in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Eclipse is fitlering requested packages. To check that out, go to **Window->Preferences->Java->Appearance->TypeFilters** - remove required package from filter list and/or uncheck *Hide forbidden references*/*Hide dscouraged references* on the bottom. Now classes are available in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the following:
[image]